# discord bot using node.js - how do i convert a message to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I'm trying to convert the message content to lower case and reply with an array element.

I have the following code, but when I use it, the bot comes online but doesn't reply. Are there any obvious errors in this snippet?

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {

 var i = Math.floor(55*Math.random());
 if (message.content.toLowerCase().message.content.includes('message') || message.content.toLowerCase().message.content.includes('msg')) {
  message.channel.startTyping();
  
  delay(3500).then(function() {
   message.channel.send(`'${quote[i]}'`);
   message.channel.stopTyping();
  });
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
message.content.toLowerCase().message.content.includes('message')
```

`message.content` is a string, so `message.content.toLowerCase()` is also a string. That means that you should not have `.toLowerCase().message.content.includes("message")` but instead just have `.toLowerCase().includes("message")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
message.channel.send(`'${quote[i]}'.toLowerCase()`);
```

Comment: I don't want to convert the quote to lowercase. I want to convert the word that triggers the quote to lowercase.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26209492)